# Cannot Route RDP Traffic Through AWS Site-to-Site VPN

Tags: networking, cisco-asa, amazon-vpc, site-to-site-vpn, cisco-vpn

Hi I have establish VPN connection to the AWS VPC, but still there are some routing issues that make RDP connections fail to initiate, because the router WAN IP is differs from the Public IP, lets say:

Router Cisco Rv042

```
Public IP:      71.xx.xx.243 (from wanip.info)
Router WAN IP:  71.xx.xx.242
```

I even port forwarded my router IP `192.x.x.1`. My question is, how can we configure the router/VPN Gateway in order to get the RDP connected, and yet the RDP works fine (site to site) router connected but not to the VPC.

Comment: Just trying to think of a few things here... will the RDP server's security group allow 71.x.x.243 to connect? You may need to add a static route to the VPN connection for the 71.xx.xx.xx subnet; say, `71.xx.xx.241/29` or whatever your proper subnet size is...

Comment: The router is behind Netgear VPN firewall fvs336gv2 and that's preventing the cisco rv042 to connect with VPC and it seems the netgear is not that easy to configure as it was in rv042